# update_post_meta after form is submited

Tags: functions, post-meta

I'm using the plugin "Formidable" to easily manage and create forms. I have set a custom post type, and created an extra post_meta.

I can use meta('test'); within the loop to show my meta value on the posts single page.

Everytime someone creates an entry by submitting the form thats on the single post page i want  the value for the meta key 'test' to be subtracted by one(updated).

The Formidable plugin comes with a action hook:

```
add_filter('frm_after_create_entry', 'after_entry_created', 30, 2);
function after_entry_created($entry_id, $form_id){
    if($form_id == 7){ //change 7 to the ID of your form
          //do stuff here
    }
}
```

I have put this in my functions.php. But how do I target the right post and right meta key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a crude example, it can be improved to ensure you're dealing with integers etc and also shortened overall for brevity but this should get you started.

```
add_filter('frm_after_create_entry', 'after_entry_created', 30, 2);
function after_entry_created($entry_id, $form_id){

    global $post;

    if($form_id == 7){ //change 7 to the ID of your form

      $previous_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true); 

      if($previous_value == null) {

        $value = 12345; //this is a starting value if nothing set
        $previous_value = $value;
        $value = $previous_value - 1; //returns 12344

      } else {

        $value = $previous_value - 1; //returns whatever previous value was - 1 

     }

      update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value, $previous_value);

    }
}
```

I'm making some assumptions without knowing if you are working with a starting value or not, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the right direction. But i don't really get it to work. I need to troubleshoot where it's going wrong. How do i check what the get_post_meta returns? And yes i got a starting value. Thanks again :)

Comment: I got it to work, but had to remove $previous_value in update_post_meta... Anyways thnx a lot :)

Comment: Hum, i don't get the "get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);" to work :/ It doesnt seem to return anything...